# How to verify presence of multiple text in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify one of the metadata present in to div as :

```
<div ng-if="XXXXXXX" class="XXXXX" >
    <div>March 01 2019, 10:00 am to</div>
    <div>March 28 2019, 6:00 pm</div>
</div>
```

Need to verify presence of all these Keywords with '01', '28', '10:00 am', '6:00 pm' except Month and Year.

What can be effective way to verify it ?

Comment: take everything in a string using getText() method, then perform split operation based on year and month. Please update the OP with String. What is the actual string and what do u want (your expected) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `<div>` will hold all the text. Locate it and check if it contains it

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("XXXXX"));
String text = element.getText();
if (text.contains("01") && text.contains("28") && ...) {
    assertTrue(true, "All keywords present");
}
```

Comment: As we are using contains, text.contains("01") will return true when the text is March 01 2019, 10:00 am or March 05 2019, 10:00 am. So I would suggest to use text.contains(" 01 ") [a space before & after]